# File Transfer But Cannot load in its respective Launcher(Adobe Pdf) - Java Server Client

Tags: java, file, serversocket, java-server, java-client

I Have a Project working for my Java Class, I am Using Socket Yes I look at a Tutorial online for help, the aim is to read a file on a server of pdf type then allow the CLient to request this File from the Sever.

My Issue It request the File but after the File is requested and stored on the Client Machine when I Hit the File to be Launch adobe says the file "Adobe could not open the File for it is not supported file type or because the file as been damage

Here is my Code Please I would appreciate if some one could assist me:

Server Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SimpleFileServer {

 public final static String FILE_TO_SEND = "‪c:/Users/Acer/Downloads/COAFlags.pdf"; // you may change this

public static void main(String args[]) {

    while (true) {
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
        Socket connectionSocket = null;
        BufferedOutputStream outToClient = null;

        try {
            welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(3248);
            connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling
        }

        if (outToClient != null) {
            File myFile = new File( FILE_TO_SEND);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = null;

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            try {
                bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                outToClient.flush();
                outToClient.close();
                connectionSocket.close();

                // File sent, exit the main method
                return;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.net.*;

public class SimpleFileClient {

private final static String serverIP = "localhost";
public final static int FILE_SIZE = 55000;
private final static int serverPort = 3248;
private final static String fileOutput = "c:/Users/Acer/Downloads/sourcedownloaded.pdf";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    byte[] aByte = new byte[FILE_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket( serverIP , serverPort );
        is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Do exception handling
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    if (is != null) {

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream( fileOutput );
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);

            do {
                    baos.write(aByte);
                    bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
            } while (bytesRead != -1);

            bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling
        }
    }
}}
```

The file i wanted transfer was 54KB okay so it wasnt out of range.

Comment: Usual problems. Ignoring the length returned by `read();` trying to fit an entire file into memory; pointless use of a `ByteArrayOutputStream;` ...

Comment: What should I use if byteArrayOutPutStream is useless

Comment: I didn't say it was useless. I said you were using it pointlessly. Everything you write to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` can be written directly to the `FileOutputStream`. The way you're doing it just wastes space and adds latency. Also the `do/while` pattern is incorrect: it will write junk if the input is empty. Indeed, your code writes junk most of the time. See @farukdgn's answer for the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you do it. You must transfer the file inside a while loop, so the buffer you use wouldn't use much memory. Server side:

```
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket();
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",9200));
while(true) //that loop provides server non-stop sending, it will response to client requests till you terminate the application.
{
    Socket received = socket.accept();
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("c:/Users/Acer/Downloads/COAFlags.pdf");
    OutputStream output = received.getOutputStream();
    int length;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    while((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    output.close(); //no need to flush because close() already does it
    input.close();
}
```

Client side:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9200);
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("c:/Users/Acer/Desktop/abc.pdf");
int length;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

while((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

output.close();
input.close();
```

Note: Buffer size is optional. 4096 is generally used.

Comment: Okay am gona try that now and get back to you

Comment: Okay I edited my code with the addition you said but am not getting any where could you tell me if I added the code you imply wrong

Comment: I've added full code so you can copy paste and try them and then analyze it.

Comment: It works Sweet now can I ask you if I were to send it back on the server should allow the server to accept new connection and read it locally while sending it to the server by using out put Stream @farukdgn

Comment: Just change inputstreams and outputstreams in the code to send file to server. Client must read from fileinputstream and write to socket's outputstream, server must read from socket's inputstream and write to fileoutputstream.

Comment: Yah Thanks again I saw that an have gone on to write a multi threading Server Dor multiple client

Answer (score 0):

New Server Code:
 import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SimpleFileServer {

```
 public final static String FILE_TO_SEND = "‪c:/Users/Acer/Downloads/COAFlags.pdf"; // you may change this

public static void main(String args[]) {

    while (true) {
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
        Socket connectionSocket = null;
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {
            welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(3248);
            connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            output = connectionSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling
        }

        if (output != null) {



            try {
                int length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(FILE_TO_SEND);
                try {
                    while((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } //no need to flush because close() already does it

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }



        }
    }
}}
```

Updated Client

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SimpleFileClient {

```
private final static String serverIP = "localhost";
public final static int FILE_SIZE = 55000;
private final static int serverPort = 3248;
private final static String fileOutput = "c:/Users/Acer/Downloads/sourcedownloaded.pdf";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[55000];
    int length;

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket( serverIP , serverPort );
        input = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Do exception handling
    }

   // ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    if (input != null) {


        FileOutputStream output = null;
        //BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream( fileOutput );
            while((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling
        }
    }
}}
```